# user not able to access the file which has privilege via group

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am facing the below problem in linux kernel 2.6.18-7.1

1. I created user  "BBC" using `adduser -D` after this `/etc/passwd` contains `"BBC:x:1010:1010:Linux User,,,:/home/BBC:/bin/sh"`
2. I created group "BBCGROUP" using `addgroup BBCGROUP`
3. added the user "BBC" to the group "BBCGROUP" using `addgroup BBC BBCGROUP` after this `etc/group` contains

   BBC:x:1010:

   BBCGROUP:x:9:BBC
4. then created the directory `mkdir /usr1 [ as root ]`
5. I created file /usr1/test.txt by using echo "hello" > /usr1/test.txt
6. ls -l /usr1 gives "-rwxrwx--x    1 root     root        5 Sep  5 14:01 test.txt"
7. chmod -R 771 /usr1
8. chown -R :BBCGROUP /usr1.

After this I expect, user "BBC" able to read/write/execute files under /usr1 .

Now "ls -l /usr1 " gives -rwxrwx--x    1 root     BBCGROUP        5 Sep  5 14:03 test.txt
9)I changed the user to "BBC" by "su -s /bin/sh BBC"
10) id command shows
uid=1010(BBC) gid=1010(BBC)
11) cd /usr1
12) I tried to modify the file echo "HELLO1" > test.txt or touch test.txt
I getting error as "sh: can't create /usr1/test.txt: Permission denied"   for user BBC.

This is the basic problem, I am facing in embedded system, any solution for this. Any configuration need to be changed? Same thing working fine in desktop linux. Any info please to solve this.

Comment: You really need to format that before I try to read it anymore.

Comment: Any particular reason your not using the tools for this, even if your just running a script post install? For example how are you ensuring shaddow is correctly setup?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the man page for passwd have the following restriction on the username field? "It should not contain capital letters."

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the `newgrp BBCGROUP` command before entering the directory.

Alternatively, you may want to change the default group for this user to BBCGROUP instead of BBC. Maybe the `addgroup` utility can do it (I have some other flavour of utilities here, so I am not sure), or you can manually change the second `:1010:` to `:9:` in the /etc/passwd file *(carefully!)*.

And by the way, this question seems to be more appropriate to https://superuser.com/ or *(better:)* https://unix.stackexchange.com/ I suppose.